# How to really filter a pandas dataset without leaving Nans everywhere

Tags: python, pandas, filter

Say I have a huge `DataFrame` that only contains a handful of cells that match the filtering I perform. How can I end up with only the values that match it (and their indexes and columns) in a new dataframe without the entire other `DataFrame` that becomes Nan. Dropping Nan's with `dropna` just removes the whole column or row and `filter` replaces non matches with Nans.
Here's my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1000, 1000)))

# this one is almost filled with Nans
df[df<0.01]
```

Comment: Can you add your code to question? How looks your conditions? How do you filter?

Comment: sure thing @jezrael , just added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need non missing values in another format you can use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
np.random.seed(2020)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 3)))

# this one is almost filled with Nans
df1 = df[df<7]
print (df1)
     0    1    2
0  0.0  NaN  3.0
1  6.0  3.0  3.0
2  NaN  NaN  0.0
3  0.0  NaN  NaN
4  3.0  NaN  2.0

df2 = df1.stack().rename_axis(('a','b')).reset_index(name='c')
print (df2)
   a  b    c
0  0  0  0.0
1  0  2  3.0
2  1  0  6.0
3  1  1  3.0
4  1  2  3.0
5  2  2  0.0
6  3  0  0.0
7  4  0  3.0
8  4  2  2.0
```

Comment: is there a way to get a Dataframe with only the values that fulfill the filtering? Just by themselves, without every other cell in the same row or without throwing away the whole row if not all of them in the row are that value?

Comment: @Mario - Not sure if understand, I try edit answer.